# ¿como cambiar las letras mayusculas a minusculas y viceversa?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-netbeans

inteto hacer este problema en java, hasta ahora solo eh logrado voltearlo. Realice un programa que lea una cadena de caracteres la escriba al revés transformando las
mayúsculas en minúsculas y viceversa, además mostrará el numero de veces que aparecen los
dígitos en la cadena.
Por ejemplo: Ingresa -> Buenos Aires 115B
Salida -> b511 SERIa SONEUb digitos -> 3
¿que puedo hacer?

```
  Scanner tex= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("ingresa el texto");
   String str = tex.nextLine();
   System.out.println("la cadena es "+ str);
   StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(str);
   str = strb.reverse().toString();
   System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Netbeans_ aquí no tiene nada que ver con las etiquetas, así que elimina sus etiquetas relacionadas. Pista: detectá el valor ASCII de cada caracter de la cadena. No te digo cómo porque debés investigarlo por tu cuenta, y hay muchísima información al respecto :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la clase [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) tiene métodos que pueden serte de utilidad para este ejercicio

> [`toUpperCase(char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char))
> Convierte el argumento de carácter a mayúsculas utilizando información de asignación de mayúsculas y minúsculas del archivo UnicodeData.

> [`toLowerCase(char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char))
> Convierte el argumento de carácter a minúsculas utilizando información de asignación de mayúsculas y minúsculas del archivo UnicodeData.

> [`isDigit(char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))
> Determina si el carácter especificado es un dígito.

para hacer uso de ellas partiremos de una cadena

```
String palabra="Buenos Aires 115B";
int cont=0;//contador para los digitos que pueden haber en la cadena
String aux="";//variable auxiliar que tomara los caracteres modificados

    for (int i=0;i<palabra.length();i++){//recorremos la cadena
       //si el caracter se encuentra alfabeticamente y en minuscula entre a-z
        if(palabra.charAt(i) >='a' && palabra.charAt(i) <= 'z'){
       // se convertira en mayuscula
             aux+=Character.toUpperCase(palabra.charAt(i));
       //si es o se  encuentra entre A-Z 
        }else if(palabra.charAt(i) >='A' && palabra.charAt(i) <= 'Z'){
       //el caracter se convierte a minuscula
             aux+=Character.toLowerCase(palabra.charAt(i));
       // si fuese un digito
        }else if(Character.isDigit(palabra.charAt(i))){
        //incluiremos en el texto 
             aux+=palabra.charAt(i);
        //aumentamos el contador
             cont++;
        }else{
        //tomamos los espacios que puedan existir en la cadena
            aux+=palabra.charAt(i);
        }
    }
//invertimos la cadena
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(aux);
    aux = strb.reverse().toString();
/impimimos la cadena inversa y le adicionamos la cantidad de digitos 
     System.out.println(aux+" "+cont);
```

**Prueba del metodo:** [Metodo](https://rextester.com/ETRBQS67466)

Comment: Es mejor siempre especificarle un locale para evitar errores.